# Link error in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

I am getting the following error `framework not found -fobjc-arc` while compiling an iOS app that previously worked fine. I have no idea what framework it cannot find. Does anyone know where I could track this down? thanks.

```
Ld /Users/baz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ConverserApp-awrbvmghzyuomheukcqjzijxvnai/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ConverserApp.app/ConverserApp normal armv7
cd /Users/baz/Dropbox/Code/_clients/Converser/ConverserApp
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -L/Users/baz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ConverserApp-awrbvmghzyuomheukcqjzijxvnai/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/baz/Dropbox/Code/_clients/Converser/ConverserApp/../mobile-api-docs.2/converser-canary -L/Users/baz/Dropbox/Code/_clients/Converser/ConverserApp/Libs/Converser -F/Users/baz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ConverserApp-awrbvmghzyuomheukcqjzijxvnai/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Applications/Reveal.app/Contents/SharedSupport/iOS-Libraries -filelist /Users/baz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ConverserApp-awrbvmghzyuomheukcqjzijxvnai/Build/Intermediates/ConverserApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/ConverserApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ConverserApp.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -framework -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MessageUI -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lz -framework Reveal -lVGConversationKit_universal -o /Users/baz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ConverserApp-awrbvmghzyuomheukcqjzijxvnai/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ConverserApp.app/ConverserApp

ld: framework not found -fobjc-arc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Check your build settings -> other linker flags and see if you can find a `-framework` in there somewhere.

Comment: This part of the linker command is *spurious*: `-framework -fobjc-arc`.

Comment: @trojanfoe, only the `-framework` is potentially wrong.  Presumably the `-fobjc-arc` is supposed to be there.

Comment: Yes, other linker flags had `-framework` in there.
I just uninstalled the SparkInspector.framework and I think it left that behind. Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a real framework - your command line contains this bit:

```
-framework -fobjc-arc
```

Which is wrong - the `-framework` flag should be followed by a framework name, not by another flag.  You need to find out where that extra `-framework` is coming from.  There are several correct `-framework` flags in that command too - notice that they all have a framework name included:  `-framework MessageUI -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics`

Comment: The extra `-framework` flag - that's why OP has to find where it's coming from and remove it.  Or, alternately, put the name of an actual framework to go with it.

Comment: Yes, again, but how does the OP solve the issue (I assume this is from Xcode, not from a Makefile, where a coder has more control...).

Comment: Who knows?  There are plenty of ways to configure the flags passed to tools in Xcode.  OP has to work that out for himself.

Comment: Weak answer then; more of a comment really.

Comment: It was other linker flags had a rogue `-framework` in there with nothing else on the line. It used to say `-framework SparkInspector` - the SparkInspector part was removed but not the -framework part when I uninstalled the inspector. Fixed now :)

Answer (score 2):

**Go to Projects--->Targets---->Build Settings--->Other Linker Flags. Click on the value side and make sure there are no extraneous [  -framework  ]  values. If so, delete them.** Notice the pattern of line [-framework], next line has a framework in quotes, next line has [-framework]. Etc. It should never end with a -framework, nor have extras. These linker flags happen after compile and make sure that the binary is linked with necessary frameworks.

[image: Other Linker Flags closeup]